# What model of Raspberry Pi is good for a local web server?

Tags: raspbian, python

I need some useful information about running a local web server in a Raspberry Pi and the best embedded system that can handle my device.

### What do I mean?

Well I've created a website using `django` + `redis` + `celery` + `postgresql`

So what I want to do with this website is to `Turn on/off LED lamp` using a `BreadBoard`. This is done by `celery` ...
actually there is a task (`celery-beat-schedule`) that should turn off/on some specific LED lamps.

And the django is the `firmware` that creates those tasks and controls my `device`

#### For example:

Imagine I have a task that represent the main job of the device (turning on/of) a I can create and run this tasks using `django-celery-beat`.

### But

The main question is how can I run this in a embedded system like Raspberry Pi. Actually what are the best hardware like `CPU RAM` this website can run on that and does not crash?

For example, is `Raspberry Pi zero w` suitable for running this web server and setup? And there is no limit to the implementation?

Of course, let me say this too. I don't want to spend too much otherwise I think the `Raspberry Pi 4` is the best.

*Updated*: Also the `OS` is linux (`Raspbian OS`) as you already know.

Comment: You are asking for opinions which is off topic.

Comment: I would recommend to build a simple RESTful server, on Rpi/RpiW/RpiPicoW.
(1) ***Rpi Pico W - Build a RESTful web server to control a  LED***
https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-run-a-webserver-on-raspberry-pi-pico-w/

(2) RESTful Web Services Tutorial - TutorialsPoint
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm

Comment: How would we know that you are using Raspberry Pi OS (different from Raspian)? There are several Linux distributions that work on the pi.

Comment: you can use an Arduino UNO for this ... any Raspberry Pi is way more powerful than UNO

Comment: Raspbian is MEANINGLESS - it could be any of 5 families of OS spanning 10 years.
Even Raspberry Pi OS is ambiguous - at last count there are 8 and there are significant differences between Buster & Bullseye.

Comment: What are you using redis and postgres for in a "simple website for controlling a led"?

Answer (score 9):

All Pi's should work for this simple set-up.

Of course, there are limits to the implementation. But for a simple set-up as yours, you are far below the limits of the humble Zero W.

Comment: Except for the Pico, which can probably still do it, but doesn't run Linux so you'll have a harder time.

Answer (score 3):

I hosted an Nginx server on a Pi 4 with 4 Gb of memory for a personal site, it worked well for local connections. Hosting a site to control a lamp should be within the capabilities of all Pi's, although Django seems a bit overkill for this. Perhaps try Flask.